# TinyMCE not working in production server

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I am using `TinyMCE` in my program. It works if I load it locally (localhost) but when I try to load it from intranet server, it does not work.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40199890/4315380) answer. Might be helpful.